# How do I integrate Asp.Net Identity in to a custom MVC/EF application?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, dbcontext

I want to understand and use ASP.Net Identity and all the tutorials I have done from the official site start with the same template and you add your models to the default context.

This seems to work in their examples, however, when I try to scaffold views off this, I seem to get errors that are not present when trying to scaffold off of a custom/smaller dbcontext (as I used to do in MVC3 EF4.1).

I am having trouble locating best practices and actual real world examples of using identity. I was wondering what should I be doing long term and if anyone knows of actual larger scale tutorials/best practices for using ASP.Net Identity?

In particular, I was wondering:

1) Should I be using two DbContexts per app: one for identity, one for my app?

2) Should I be extending my DbContext for identity?

3) Should I be extending the ASP.Net Identity DBContext for my app?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is if you start a fresh application with authentication and then move your existing code over - that way everything works, and you can then customize the templates. Regarding your questions,

1) As of EF6, you can use several `DbContexts` with the same Db, so I would generally use the given one for the Identity stuff and define my own context for my own data

2) Would not do that, rather do 3) if I only use one `DbContext`.